# Count of subsetsum problem, how to debug where the solution is not working?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

So I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/perfect-sum-problem5633/1#) :

> Given an array arr[] of integers and an integer sum, the task is to
> count all subsets of the given array with a sum equal to a given sum.
>
> Note: Answer can be very large, so, output answer modulo 10^9+7

Now this is the solution I'm trying out here:

```cpp
class Solution{
    private:
    vector<vector<int>> t;
    public:
    Solution() {
        t.resize(1001, vector<int> (1001,-1));
    }
    int perfectSum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
    {  
        long long int result = fmod(sumrecursive(arr, n, sum),(pow(10,9)+7));
        return result;
    }
    
    long long int sumrecursive(int arr[], int n, int sum){
        
        if(sum==0){
            return 1;
        } 
        if(n==0){
            return 0;
        }
        
        if(t[n][sum] != -1){
            return t[n][sum];
        }
        
        if(arr[n-1]>sum){
            return t[n][sum] = sumrecursive(arr, n-1, sum);
        } else {
            return t[n][sum] = sumrecursive(arr,n-1, sum-arr[n-1]) + sumrecursive(arr, n-1, sum);
        }
    }
      
};
```

Now this code is not working after some certain input:

[image]

I don't know on how to proceed in solving this problem at this point. Ideally according to the code I have written the input is within the grasp of the code and output should've been correct but unfortunately it is not the case. I wanted to ask if someone could spot on where the problem might be in the code or guide me on how to debug where the problem is in the code.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not overflowing your return or cached values? It's hard to say without seeing a given input, but you're using a vector of int to cache a result of type long long int. Seeing a reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably encountering [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) along the way.

You are taking the mod only right before ending the function, but your cache is of type `int`, so when placing too big numbers - you are losing some data due to overflow.

Comment: Yeah I believe that's the case as well. Do you have an idea how I can solve this overflow problem?

Comment: @Nike Do the modolus before whenever you are summing.